# Select XMLNode with XPath

Tags: c#, xml

I have seen multiple post with this example but for some reason all options I try return an empty XmlNodeList. What am I missing?

My XML:

```
<string xmlns='http://ws.jobboard.com/resumes/'>
<Packet>
<Errors />
<PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
<SearchTime>02/25/2014 10:11:47</SearchTime>
<FirstRec>1</FirstRec>
<LastRec>100</LastRec>
<Hits>206816</Hits>
<MaxPage>40</MaxPage>
<Results>
  <ResumeResultItem_V3>
    <ContactEmail></ContactEmail>
    <ContactName>Lisa Yada</ContactName>
    <HomeLocation>US-CO-Lakewood</HomeLocation>
    <LastUpdate>2014/2/24</LastUpdate>
    <ResumeTitle>Web Design &amp; Developement</ResumeTitle>
    <JobTitle>Web Design &amp; Developement</JobTitle>
    <RecentEmployer>Some Company</RecentEmployer>
    <RecentJobTitle>Web Design</RecentJobTitle>
    <RecentPay>0</RecentPay>
    <ResumeID>RHV47X78Z5CN56</ResumeID>
    <UserDID>UHT6R86LL8C581</UserDID>
    <ContactEmailMD5>93ce261b843f58962f9</ContactEmailMD5>
    <ActionType />
    <HighestDegree>Bachelor's Degree</HighestDegree>
    <MonthsOfExperience>40</MonthsOfExperience>
    <LastActivity>2/24/2014 1:22:19 PM</LastActivity>
  </ResumeResultItem_V3> ...
```

and my code:

```
                XmlDocument jobsdoc = new XmlDocument();
                    jobsdoc.LoadXml(xmlstring);

                    XmlNodeList xnList = jobsdoc.SelectNodes("/string/Packet/Results/ResumeResultItem_V3");
                    foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
                    {
                        DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
                        dr["ContactName"] = xn["ContactName"].InnerText;
                        dr["ResumeTitle"] = xn["ResumeTitle"].InnerText; 
                        ...
                        table.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }

                    return table;
```

I have tried many variations of "/string/Packet/Results/ResumeResultItem_V3" to no avail. The ws is a third party so I have no control over the format of the XML. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [namespacemanager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your [SelectNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bektfx9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) call because your xml root node has a namespace *`http://ws.jobboard.com/resumes/`*

Notice that your XPath needs to explicitely use the namespace-alias.

```
NameTable nt = new NameTable();
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("r", "http://ws.jobboard.com/resumes/");

XmlDocument jobsdoc = new XmlDocument(nt);
jobsdoc.LoadXml(xmlstring);

var xnList = jobsdoc.SelectNodes(
                "/r:string/r:Packet/r:Results/r:ResumeResultItem_V3",
                nsmgr);
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    // rest of your code
}
```